# Custom react-native circle menu help needed

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I need to build a custom circle menu in react-native. I am currently building this menu with expo. It needs to have a circle in the middle of the screen with a logo/text and when you press and hold on the circle, smaller circles buttons come out from the middle and grow into place around the main circle, evenly spaced. Then, while still pressing, as you move your finger towards these smaller circles, they get bigger to reveal an icon and or text. When you release your finger on one of these outer circle buttons, it then takes you to that part of the app.

The closest module I found for my need is this one:

https://github.com/Ramotion/react-native-circle-menu

It did not work out of the box. I had to modify it to get it working with the most recent react-native/expo and the progress portion also doesn't work, so I commented that out as well.

As far as my need and what I have, I was able to get the circle in the middle with text, you press and hold and the smaller circle buttons come out and are evenly spaces around it, but when you drag to them and let go, im not sure which events on which components would register how I need.

Here is the code that renders the main menu button:

```
        return <Animated.View style={{
            transform: [
                {
                    scaleX: this.state.animation.interpolate({
                        inputRange: [0, .2, .75, 1],
                        outputRange: [1.5, 1.2, .5, 1]
                    })
                },
                {
                    scaleY: this.state.animation.interpolate({
                        inputRange: [0, .2, .75, 1],
                        outputRange: [1.5, 1.2, .5, 1]
                    })
                }
            ]
        }}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPressIn={this.openMenu}
                onPressOut={this.closeMenu}
                style={styles.closedButton}
                activeOpacity="1">
                <Text style={styles.closedButtonText}>XYZ</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </Animated.View>
```

This renders the smaller circle buttons that are around the outside of the main menu button above:

```
    renderActions() {
        if (!this.state.active) {
            return null
        }

        // Defines the amount of angle to increase for each item so they do not overlap
        const increase = Math.PI * 2 / this.props.items.length;

        // Define initial angle
        let angle = -Math.PI / 2;

        // Loop through each action (item) to add them to the display
        return this.props.items.map((item, index) => {

            // Angle first starts at the initial angle
            const btnAngle = angle;

            // Then increases the angle by 'increase' for each button
            angle += increase;

            // Displays the individual action (item)
            return <ActionIcon
                key={index}
                animation={this.state.animation}
                angle={btnAngle}
                bgColor={this.props.bgColor}
                buttonColor={item.color}
                icon={item.name}
                radius={this.props.radius - this.props.itemSize}
                onPress={() => {
                    this.closeMenu();
                    this.props.onPress(index);
                }}
                size={this.props.itemSize}
                style={[styles.actionContainer, { position: 'absolute' }]}
            />
        })
    }
```

and finally, here is how the circle menu is being called from the main App.js

```
  items = [
    {
      name: 'md-home',
      color: '#298CFF',
    },
    {
      name: 'md-search',
      color: '#30A400',
    },
    {
      name: 'md-time',
      color: '#FF4B32',
    },
    {
      name: 'md-settings',
      color: '#8A39FF',
    },
    {
      name: 'md-navigate',
      color: '#FF6A00',
    },
  ];

  onPress = index => console.log(`${this.items[index].name} icon pressed!`);

  render() {
    return <View style={styles.container}>
      <CircleMenu
        bgColor="#0E1329"
        items={this.items}
        onPress={this.onPress}
      />
    </View>
  }
```

If there is any other information I can provide, please let me know. Thanks in advance.